FileSystemWatcher events do not honor AsyncLocal value on .NET Framework. Is there a better workaround available?
The start of this issue was during an upgrade of NLog (see issue).
Summary: I have a legacy application that uses FileSystemWatcher and I wanted to upgrade NLog from version 4 to 5. Internally this includes a switch from CallContext to AsyncLocal. If I try to access the value of the AsyncLocal inside the raised event of the watcher it is not available on .NET Framework 4.8 but on .NET 6+.
Here is a repro test (xUnit) that fails on .NET Framework 4.8
private readonly static AsyncLocal<string> s_test = new AsyncLocal<string>();

[Fact]
public void AsyncLocalTest()
{
    const string EXPECTED_VALUE = "YES";
    s_test.Value = EXPECTED_VALUE;

    string basePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    try
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);

        FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(basePath) {
            EnableRaisingEvents = true
        };

        string GetProperty() => s_test.Value ?? "";

        using (fileSystemWatcher)
        {
            Assert.Equal(EXPECTED_VALUE, GetProperty());

            using (ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
            {
                string result = "";
                fileSystemWatcher.Created += (object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) => {
                    result = GetProperty();
                    resetEvent.Set();
                };

                string filePath = Path.Combine(basePath, "abc.txt");

                // trigger the event
                File.WriteAllText(filePath, "YES");

                Assert.True(resetEvent.WaitOne(5000));
                Assert.Equal(EXPECTED_VALUE, result); // <!-- fails here because result is "" and not "YES"
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Directory.Delete(basePath, true);
    }
}

I read the source code of the FileSystemWatcher and found that the SynchronizingObject may do the job for me. So I wrote a basic implementation that captures the ExecutionContext (AsyncLocal uses that internally).
private sealed class FileSystemWatcherSynchronizingObject : ISynchronizeInvoke
{
    private readonly ExecutionContext? _executionContext = ExecutionContext.Capture();

    private object? Run(Delegate method, object?[]? args)
    {
        if (_executionContext != null)
        {
            object? result = null;
            ExecutionContext.Run(_executionContext, _ => result = method.DynamicInvoke(args), null);

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return method.DynamicInvoke(args);
        }
    }

    public bool InvokeRequired => true;

    public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Delegate method, object?[]? args) => Task.Run(() => Run(method, args));

    public object? EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result) => ((Task<object?>)result).Result;

    public object? Invoke(Delegate method, object?[]? args) => Run(method, args);
}

Now we just have to attach this to the FileSystemWatcher if we are on .NET Framework 4.8 and the test succeeds:
        FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(basePath) {
            EnableRaisingEvents = true,
#if NET48_OR_GREATER
            SynchronizingObject = new FileSystemWatcherSynchronizingObject()
#endif
        };


As I do not have any deep knowledge about these things, I wanted to know if there is any better approach or any better implementation of FileSystemWatcherSynchronizingObject. I assume that there is a better way than Task.Run(...) in BeginInvoke.
